# Tablayout with viewpager not working

Tags: android

I have tablayout with viewpager set on it. my problem is fragament are not displaying on tab change . it shows only tabs but not the below attached fragment view with it , what is problem I can't figure it out.

In my MainActivity, my code for tablayout and view pager is like this :-

```
     categoryViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
            categoryViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
            categoryViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
            categoryPagerAdapter = new CategoryPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            categoryViewPager.setAdapter(categoryPagerAdapter);


            categoryTabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
            categoryTabs.setupWithViewPager(categoryViewPager);

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                categoryTabs.getTabAt(i).setText(categoryList[i]);
            }
```

I have layout is in Nested scroll view  :-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/layout_toolbar_colored" />


    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_clinic"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_clinic_images"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="180dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:scrollbars="horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/placeholder_image" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/clinic_details"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/iv_clinic_images"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvClinicLabel"
                        style="@style/HeaderPrimary"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                        android:text="@string/clinic_name" />

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/rl_clinic_rating"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/green_round_corner"
                        android:gravity="center">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/clinic_mood"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:padding="4dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/green_happy" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_rating"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/clinic_mood"
                            android:padding="4dp"
                            android:text="@string/user_rating_secondary"
                            android:textColor="@color/positive"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                </RelativeLayout>


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_clinic_offers"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/clinic_details"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-regular"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:paddingRight="16dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/treatment_session"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout_doctors"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_clinic_offers"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/doc_title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgDoctors"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/doctors"
                        android:textColor="@color/treatment_session"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0.9dp"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/doc_title"
                        android:background="@color/divider_line" />

                </RelativeLayout>


                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_doctor_images"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/layout_doctors"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />


                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ll_doctor_details"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/layout_doctors"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:weightSum="1">

                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:id="@+id/doctor_image"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="64dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.2"
                        android:src="@drawable/account_circle" />

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/rl_doctor_details"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:paddingLeft="8dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_doc_name"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:ellipsize="end"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="@string/doc_id"
                            android:textColor="@color/treatment_session"
                            android:textSize="14sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_doc_qualification"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_doc_name"
                            android:ellipsize="end"
                            android:textColor="@color/treatment_session"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_doc_experience"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_doc_qualification"
                            android:ellipsize="end"
                            android:textColor="@color/profile_subtext"
                            android:textSize="10sp" />

                    </RelativeLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/layout_clinic"
                android:padding="8dp">

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/resend_otp"
                    app:tabTextColor="@color/black" />

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/container"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tabs" />


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/treatment"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/my_treatments"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_treatment_head"
                    style="@style/HeaderSecondary"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/treatment"
                    android:text="@string/treatment_label"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/divider"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/container"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:background="@color/divider"
                    android:visibility="gone"/>

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_treatment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/divider"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:scrollbars="horizontal"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

and my Adapter is :-

```
private class CategoryPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public CategoryPagerAdapter(FragmentManager supportFragmentManager) {
        super(supportFragmentManager);
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new DummyTreatmentFragment();
            case 1:
                return new DummyOffersFragment();
            case 2:
                return new DummyCentersFragment();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }


}
```

Comment: are you sure, it is not displayed, everything looks OK to me!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
      categoryTabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
       categoryViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
       for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            categoryTabs.getTabAt(i).setText(categoryList[i]);
        }

        categoryPagerAdapter = new CategoryPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        categoryViewPager.setAdapter(categoryPagerAdapter);

        categoryTabs.setupWithViewPager(categoryViewPager);
        categoryViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
        categoryViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
```

try set up the tablayout first before calling `setupWithViewPager`

Also make your viewpager `android:layout_height="match_parent"`

Comment: I think it's because of nested scroll view which scrolls vertically and view pager which scroll horizontal? I guess not sure !

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 sure, I am just seeing it a strange problem, did not meant to say you answer is wrong or something:)

Comment: @sanket post the full xml layout did u try the change?

Comment: i'm trying above code and yes i'll post my full xml code  in1min